# REGEX search only affecting last occurence in preg_replace function in PHP error

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, highlight

I have a function highlighting word for a glossary.  I created a regex to replace occurrence of word that are preceded and followed by word starting/ending characters like spaces, commas, HTML tags, etc.  It also incorporate plurals and 'féminin' version of the word (french is a complicated language) in glossary in the highlight (the [esx]{0,2} part). The \x{00A0} stands for `&nbsp;` because it is intended to work in HTML text too.

It all works fine except I realized it only change the last occurrence of the word in the targeted text.  Any idea how to correct that ?

My simplified version of the function for analysis :

```php
function highlight_word ($word, $content) {

     $search = "#(.*)([\s\x{00A0} ,\.-;\(\)\">])(" . $part . ")([esx]{0,2})([,\.;<\"-\)\(]{0,1}[\s\x{00A0} ,\.;\"-\)\(<])(.*)#i";
     $content = preg_replace( $search, '\1\2<strong>\3\4</strong>\5\6', $content );

     return $content;

}
```

Thanks!!!!

It took a while before I realised that only last occurrence was replaced.  I initially though it was not discovering some words, but its because these word occurred later in string.  The last occurrence being correctly highlighted.

I though `preg_replace` was replacing all occurrences.  Should I use some kind of `preg_replace_callback()` ??

Comment: Please [edit] your question with sample data that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: FYI: `.` and `(` and `)` don't need to be escaped in a character class.  `{0,1}` is more simply expressed as `?`.  If you are going to concatenation `$part`, then wrap the other literals in single quotes so that you don't need to escape double quotes inside your pattern.  If you are expecting accented/French characters, you might benefit from throwing a `u` pattern modifier at the end.  As Nick mentioned, we need a [mcve].  See those `(.*)` (greedy matching) subpatterns? -- if you don't have any newlines, you are going to match the entire string (never more than one match).

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Two greedy quantifiers in the same regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51507673/2943403)

Comment: Oh, and that hyphen in your character class: `\.-;` matches a single character in the range between `.` (index 46) and `;` (index 59). ...just in case that wasn't intentional.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I understood that the (.*) on each sides make you only match one occurence.  I edited the rgex like this and it all works perfectly : 
            $search = "/([\s\x{00A0} ,\.-;\(\)\">])(" . $part . ")([esx]{0,2})([\s\x{00A0} ,\.;\"-\)\(<])/iu";